# ERROR 1070: Could not resolve Pigstorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I get error when I am trying to load data set in pig

```
grunt> movies = LOAD'/home/cloudera/Documents/movies_data.csv' USING Pigstorage(',') as (id,name,year,rating,duration);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the case of Storage in PigStorage. It looks like a typo to me.

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. For some reason when I am in cloudera terminal and being as normal user it was giving me error as you mentioned, just entered in as a `'super user'` as below and tried running pig being a root. It worked with no errors. Wasted lot of time on this to know what I am missing here.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo su
[root@quickstart cloudera]# pig
**loading pig**
grunt>x = load '/pig/sales' as (name,price);
**no errors**
grunt>
```